# Как определить координаты gps точки на плане? если известны координаты 4-ех его углов

Tags: геометрия, геолокация, gps, координаты

Есть некая картинка/план, который соотносится с координатами gps нашего мира, а именно известны координаты gps всех его четырёх углов. Ширина и высота картинки также известны. Как можно посчитать координаты gps некой точки на этом плане, если мне будут известы только координаты gps четырёх углов картинки, и "пиксельные координаты" выбранной точки на плане?

1)Картинка может быть повёрнута относительно своего центра на любой градус
2)Учитывать кривизну земли не обязательно(не такой большой план)

Я пытался преоброзовывать через плоские координаты Гаусса-Крюгера, но слишком сложно для такой задачи. Через вектора тоже не получилось.

**Готовый код решения вопроса(Java)**

*Спасибо [Stanislav Volodarskiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/416121/stanislav-volodarskiy) за предоставленные формулы*

```java
private static ImmutablePair<Double, Double> convertCoords(
        double initialWidth,
        double initialHeight,
        double targetX,
        double targetY,
        double pointLTX, // LeftTop
        double pointLTY, // LeftTop
        double pointRTX, // RightTop
        double pointRTY, // RightTop
        double pointRBX, // RightBottom
        double pointRBY, // RightBottom
        double pointLBX, // LeftBottom
        double pointLBY  // LeftBottom
        ) {

        double c00 = ((initialWidth - targetX) * (initialHeight - targetY))/ (initialWidth * initialHeight);
        double cw0 = (targetX * (initialHeight - targetY)) / (initialWidth * initialHeight);
        double c0h = ((initialWidth - targetX) * targetY) / (initialWidth * initialHeight);
        double cwh = (targetX * targetY) / (initialWidth * initialHeight);

        Double x = c00 * pointLTX + cw0 * pointRTX + c0h * pointLBX + cwh * pointRBX;
        Double y = c00 * pointLTY + cw0 * pointRTY + c0h * pointLBY + cwh * pointRBY;

        return new ImmutablePair<>(x,y);
    }
```

Comment: координаты джпс на плоскости или в пространстве? В смысле, высота точек над поверхностью известна? И чего именно координаты известны? Текущий текст допускает несколько трактовок.

Comment: @Эникейщик высота не имеет значения, тобишь на плоскости. Известны gps координаты всех 4-ех углов картинки, а также случайные "пиксельные координаты" на этой самой картинке.

Comment: ну если плоская картинка плоско лежит на плоской земле, то все решается парой уравнений через пропорции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> g00 - GPS координаты в пикселе (0, 0)
> gw0 - GPS координаты в пикселе (w, 0)
> g0h - GPS координаты в пикселе (0, h)
> gwh - GPS координаты в пикселе (w, h)
> x, y - координаты пикселя
> ```

Тогда:

> ```
> c00 = ((w - x) * (h - y)) / (w * h)
> cw0 = ( x      * (h - y)) / (w * h)
> c0h = ((w - x) *  y     ) / (w * h)
> cwh = ( x      *  y     ) / (w * h)
> gxy = c00 * g00 + cw0 * gw0 + c0h * g0h + cwh * gwh
> ```

Comment: прошу прощение за не понимание. в gxy что в итоге получается? lat, lon?

Comment: В `gxy` то же что и в `g00`, `gw0`, `g0h`, `gwh`.

Comment: всё равно не могу понять, gps координата это два числа, lat и lon. а в gxy получается одно, при том не совсем понял операцию умножения `c00` на сущность из двух чисел `g00`, которая является gps координатами левого верхнего угла картинки, и содержит по сути два числа.

Comment: Вектора умножаются на вещественные коэффициенты поэлементно. Вектора суммируются поэлементно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! а если в той же ситуации известны gps координаты точки, как узнать её пиксельные координаты? пробовал развернуть формулу, посчитав `w` и `h` как длину отрезка между gps координатами соответствующих точек, чтот не получилось ничего.

Comment: Систему уравнений `(1 - a)(1 - b)g00 + a(1 - b)gw0 + (1 - a)b g0h + a b gwh = gxy` решите относительно `a` и `b`. Или задайте отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Создал [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1454933/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8b-xy%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82)

заранее спасибо.