# Как определить координаты XY(пиксельные) точки на плане? если известны координаты gps 4-ех его углов

Tags: геометрия, геолокация, gps, координаты

Есть план картинка, у которого известны ширина, высота, а также координаты gps всех углов плана.

Как получить пиксельные координаты случайной точки на плане, если известны её gps координаты?

- План на "карте" может находиться под любым углом.
- Высота над уровнем моря не важна, кривизной земли тоже можно пренебречь.
- Заранее известно что точка 100% лежит на плане, и не может лежать за его границами
- План строго имеет прямоугольную форму

**Go шаблон**

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    Num     uint    `json:"num" xml:"num" bson:"num" sql:"unique_index:idx_point_num"`
    X       float64 `json:"x" xml:"x" bson:"x"`
    Y       float64 `json:"y" xml:"y" bson:"y"`
    LatLng
}

type LatLng struct {
    Lat float64 `json:"lat" xml:"lat" bson:"lat"`
    Lon float64 `json:"lon" xml:"lon" bson:"lon"`
}

func main() {
    points := make([]Point, 4)
    points[0].Num = 1 //Левый Верхний
    points[0].X = 0.0
    points[0].Y = 0.0
    points[0].LatLng.Lat = 59.94082501317843
    points[0].LatLng.Lon = 30.313837582926084

    points[1].Num = 2 //Правый Верхний
    points[1].X = 1182.0
    points[1].Y = 0.0
    points[1].LatLng.Lat = 59.934845940050806
    points[1].LatLng.Lon = 30.36341272121419

    points[2].Num = 3 //Правый Нижний
    points[2].X = 1182.0
    points[2].Y = 174.0
    points[2].LatLng.Lat = 59.931189953842654
    points[2].LatLng.Lon = 30.361653262718022

    points[3].Num = 4 //Левый Нижний
    points[3].X = 0.0
    points[3].Y = 174.0
    points[3].LatLng.Lat = 59.937169032133106
    points[3].LatLng.Lon = 30.312080655319818
    
    targetPoint := LatLng{Lat:59.937169032133106, Lon:30.312080655319818}

    X := ???
    Y := ???

    fmt.Println(X)
    fmt.Println(Y)
}
```

```
points - массив точек (кол-во 4) описывающий координаты всех 4 углов прямоугольника/плана
targetPoint - gps координаты точки, пиксельные координаты которой требуется определить.
```

Comment: @Эникейщик не повтор, а обратная версия. Там попросили отдельный вопрос для обратной операции, я и создал. Связь данных вопросов отображается справа в секции "Связанные"

Comment: Это то же самое. Просто заменить одни переменные на другие. Примерно как был вопрос "известна сумма чисел А и Б, и число А. Как найти число Б". Вам дали ответ, а теперь вы спрашиваете как найти число А, если известно Б.

Comment: @Эникейщик я же написал уже там, что в обратную сторону формула указанная там, не работает. Просто заменив входные "числа" пикселей, на коорднаты gps не дают обратного эффекта. Человек давший ответ, указал так же на это, попросив отдельный вопрос для разъяснения решения.

Comment: @Эникейщик, формула в том вопросе была для прямоугольника ориентированного по осям (в экранных координатах). В GPS координатах прямоугольник может иметь произвольную ориентацию. Формулы будут сложнее. Поэтому я попросил задать новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

за неимением ответа решил через сопоставление прямоугольников, с последующим расчётом через треугольник. В пределах одного здания, и даже стадиона, точность конвертации координат очень велика. Проверил и в северном и в южном полушарии, и при разных углах поворота плана относительно карты мира.

```java
    private static ImmutablePair<Integer,Integer> GetPixelFromGps(
        CalibrationPoints[] points, //массив из 4 точек, обозначающих углы плана
        GpsCoordinates gps, // координаты точки в gps
        double width, // ширина плана
        double height // высота плана
    ) {

        double w = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates( //расстояние от левого вернего угла до правого верхнего, он же width в километрах
            points[0].getLat(),
            points[0].getLon(),
            points[1].getLat(),
            points[1].getLon()
        );

        double h = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates( //расстояние от левого вернего угла до левого нижнего, он же height в километрах
            points[0].getLat(),
            points[0].getLon(),
            points[3].getLat(),
            points[3].getLon()
        );

        double x0 = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates( //расстояние от левого вернего угла до точки, в километрах
            points[0].getLat(),
            points[0].getLon(),
            gps.getLat(),
            gps.getLon()
        );

        double x1 = distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates( //расстояние от правого вернего угла до точки, в километрах
            meta.getCalibrationPoints()[1].getLat(),
            meta.getCalibrationPoints()[1].getLon(),
            gps.getLat(),
            gps.getLon()
        );

        BigDecimal kefX = BigDecimal.valueOf(w).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(meta.getWidth()), 20, RoundingMode.UP); // коеф. отношения ширины в километрах к пикселям
        BigDecimal kefY = BigDecimal.valueOf(h).divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(meta.getHeight()), 20, RoundingMode.UP); //коеф. отношения высоты в километрах к пикселям

        double pX = (w + x0 + x1) / 2; // полупериметр
        BigDecimal zX = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(pX * (pX - w) * (pX - x0) * (pX- x1))).multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(2)).divide(new BigDecimal(w),20, RoundingMode.UP); // высота треугольника
        BigDecimal xtX = BigDecimal.valueOf(Math.sqrt(BigDecimal.valueOf( x0 * x0 ).subtract(zX.multiply(zX)).doubleValue())); // катет треугольника
        BigDecimal x = xtX.divide(kefX,20, RoundingMode.UP);
        BigDecimal y = zX.divide(kefY,20, RoundingMode.UP);
        return new ImmutablePair<Integer,Integer>(Math.round( x.doubleValue()), Math.round(y.doubleValue()) );
    }

    private static double distanceInKmBetweenEarthCoordinates(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2) {
        double earthRadiusKm = 6371.0;
        double dLat = degreeToRadian(lat2-lat1);
        double dLon = degreeToRadian(lon2 - lon1);
        lat1 = degreeToRadian(lat1);
        lat2 = degreeToRadian(lat2);

        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2)*Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.sin(dLon/2)*Math.sin(dLon/2)*Math.cos(lat1)*Math.cos(lat2);
        double c = 2*Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

        return earthRadiusKm * c;
    }
```

для наглядности

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]